# How does one remove a new line in a cell in a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I frequently have a problem when entering a row of data that one or more cells will get a spurious newline at the end of their data, and that row will become double-tall.  Sometimes I can guess the offending cell, click on it, backspace out the newline, which also removes the last character of the previous row, and then TAB to the next cell.  Sometimes this works, sometimes it doesn't.  Lately, I've just become resigned to having sheets with inconsistent row height.

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|     | B   |     |
| A   |     | C   |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Example: If I click in Cell B, it is B plus a newline.  If I hit backspace, I go up a row and remove the B.  If I type B again, and hit TAB, then *maybe* the cell will become single-height, or *maybe* the cell will remain double-height.

Comment: Can't you just delete the newline? Put your cursor right after the 'B' and press delete?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've not been able to reproduce this.

Comment: Can you share a spreadsheet where this happens? Also, is your objective to remove all newlines from the cells, wherever they may have occurred, or only some?

Comment: Did you tried with your browse in private / incognito / safe mode? What OS and brower are you using? Take a look to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79171/web-app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it

Comment: Is this vertical inconsistence caused by varying cell alignments rather than newline characters? Try selecting these cells and setting their alignment rule to top-align.

Comment: If the second cell does contain B and a newline, you may be having trouble editing vs. replacing cell text. Select a cell and start typing to replace the entire cell text. *Or* select a cell, then hit Enter (or just double-click the cell) to start editing its contents; then you can backspace out the trailing newline.

Comment: I am using Linux.  In Chrome, _backspace / replace-letter / tab removes_ the extra vertical white space.  In Firefox, _backspace / replace-letter / tab_ does not remove the extra vertical white space.  @NormalHuman has an effective solution to clean up screwy white space within Firefox, but would love an in-line solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove extraneous whitespace (new lines, tabs, spaces) at the beginning or at the end of the cells, one can use `trim` command. For example, suppose your current data range is A2:F20. In another part of the sheet, enter

```
=arrayformula(trim(A2:F20))
```

then copy the results and *paste values* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> or an equivalent) back to the original range.

If you only want to remove linebreaks (not other types of whitespace) at the beginning or the end, do the same thing but using the formula

```
=arrayformula(regexreplace(A2:F20, "^\n|\n$", ""))
```

And if you want to remove **all** linebreaks (wherever they appear), use

```
=arrayformula(regexreplace(A2:F20, "\n", ""))
```

Comment: This is very much the idea, thanks.  Is there a way to do this in-place without having to paste the data back in?

Comment: Yes, but it requires a script. `getValues`, process each with JavaScript method `replace` using a regular expression as above, then `setValues`. But putting this together will be more trouble than copy-pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution (for data only).

These steps remove hidden code causing the extra line in the cell:

- Select the cell that is formatting oddly
- Select and copy the text in the formula bar
- Click in a different cell, then click back into the oddly formatted cell
- Paste the contents back into that cell